# Creating javadoc with tags using ant

Tags: ant, javadoc

I have commented my java source code with javadoc using tags like {@see myPackage.MyClass}.

I have to generate javadoc with ant from terminal but I have got this warning:

```
[javadoc] src/calendar/annotation/DataType.java:11: warning - Tag @see cannot be used in inline documentation.  It can only be used in the following types of documentation: overview, package, class/interface, constructor, field, method.
```

In build.xml is this line:

```
<javadoc  sourcepath="${sourceDir}" destdir="${docDir}" windowtitle="MyProject" />
```

Can anybody help me, please?

Edit:

I am using it correctly. For example I have

```
/**
 * <p>Metoda provede požadovaný dotaz do databáze za použití předaných parametrů.
 * Pokud jsou parametry nedostatečně nedefinované, SQL dotaz neexistuje nebo nastane
 * problém s komunikací, dojde k vygenerování {@see calendar.exception.LoadException}.
 * Pokud žádné entity neodpovídají požadavku, dochází k vrácení prázdného seznamu.
 * V případě, že nějaké entity odpovídají požadovanému pravidlu, jsou načteny především ty,
 * které již jsou definovány v persistenční vrstvě. Pokud tam entity nejsou zavedeny, dochází
 * k jejich načtení z databáze.</p>
 * @param entityClass
 * @param query
 * @param params
 * @return
 * @throws calendar.exception.LoadException
 */
<EntityClass extends AbstractEntity> Collection<EntityClass> find( Class<EntityClass> entityClass, String query, Map<String, Object> params ) throws LoadException;
```

Comment: popup hint in Netbeans IDE accept my javadoc and shows it with no problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Shouldn't that be [@link](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/tooldocs/windows/javadoc.html#%7B%40link%7D) instead of [@see](http://java.sun.com/j2se/javadoc/writingdoccomments/#multiple@see)?

http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/tooldocs/windows/javadoc.html#%7B%40link%7D

Answer (score 1):

In Datatype.java, you are using @see in a comment in your code in a place Javadoc does not allow.  Specifically, it looks like you have something like:

```
/**
  *...@see...
  */
void foo() {
}
```

Where it should be

```
/**
  * ...
  * @see bla
 /*
 void foo() {
     ...
 }
```

Comment: The @see needs to be at the end of the comment, not in the middle